# How to compile a bunch of test C++ files at once with a Makefile in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I have a Makefile problem to compile a medium-size project on Linux systems. My idea is to keep the Makefile as simple as possible and let the Makefile do all the work. I have several source codes (in source/src) but also a couple of test-files to test each library (in source/test). The Makefile is here:

```
DHOME         = ${HOME}/Project
DSRC          = ${DHOME}/source/src
DINCLUDE      = ${DHOME}/source/include
BIN           = ${DHOME}/target/bin
DirObj        = ${DHOME}/target/obj
DirLib        = ${DHOME}/target/lib

INCLUDES      = -I${DINCLUDE} 
DLIB          = ${DHOME}/target/lib
LIBS          = -L${DLIB} -lm ${DLIB}/dclass.a

CXX           = g++ -g ${INCLUDES} -L${DLIB}
MAKE          = ${CXX} -O -Wall -fPIC -c

TESTS =  test_FCity test_FPlane
o_base  =  DPara.o  DString.o  FCommand.o  FInput.o

${o_base}: %.o: $(DSRC)/%.cc
      $(MAKE) $(CFLAGS) $< -o ${DirObj}/$@ 

dclass: $(o_base)
      ar -rs ${DirLib}/dclass.a ${DirObj}/*.o

TEST_SOURCE = $(wildcard test/test_*.cc)


test: ${o_base} dclass
      ${CXX} ${TEST_SOURCE} -o ${BIN}/$@ ${LIBS}

main: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)
      ${CXX} /src/main.c -o ${BIN}/main ${LIBS}
```

What I want to do with `make main` is to compile and link the main code (`main.cc`) [untested in the above Makefile], and with `make test` to automatically compile and link EACH file in the directory `source/test` (and put them into `target/bin`). Now, on running this Makefile each library seem to get compiled, but I get this error:

```
multiple definition of `main'
```

Not wondering, as I try to compile some test scripts which all have a `main()` function. Any idea how to solve this issue, and how to improve the above Makefile? And maybe some idea of how to reduce the amount of files given in the`o_base` line?

Thanks
  Alex

Comment: Did you use `remake -x` to debug your Makefile?

Comment: where is the definition of SOURCES, btw ?

Comment: I did not use `remake -X`, and SOURCES is actually wrong, as this line is untested and not used yet (just a kind of placeholder).

Answer (score 0):

You analysis is right, you try to link in your test target all .o-files which should result in different executables into one file.

As you want for each file in TEST_SOURCE a resulting executable, you have to call the compiler for each seperate. One way to achieve this is to write in the rule a (bash) loop, iterating over all elements of TEST_SOURCE, and call the compiler for each one.

The "makefile"-ier approach would be to define the dependencies right, i.e. you define that test depends additionally on the targets of TEST_SOURCE (i.e.you define the executables e.g. like TEST_EXEC=$(TEST_SOURCE:.o=_exec)) and use the compiler invocation as rule for the TEST_EXEC generation.

**EDIT:** More verbose:

You need the name of the executables of the tests: (I have now not used the ending _exec, but used just the basename) (Attention - this assumes that each .cc is a test on its own, but has there are already a TESTS variable I assume it is maybe not the case):

```
TEST_EXEC = $(TEST_SOURCE:.cc=)
```

Now we must say how to build one of those test executables:

```
${TEST_EXEC}: % : %.cc dclass ${o_base}
        ${CXX} $< -o $@               # fit this line to your needs
```

and finally we tell him that our target tests depends on all those test executables:

```
test: ${TEST_EXEC}
        echo we have nothing to do here, so we just emit "Tests created"
```

Comment: I made the following addition: `TEST_EXEC=$(TEST_SOURCE:.o=_exec))` an changed the line after `test: ..` to `${CXX} ${TEST_EXE} -o ${BIN}/$@ ${LIBS}`m, but now I get a `undefined reference to `main'` error. Maybe I was misunderstanding something in your suggestion?

Comment: Ok, then I have to switch to more verbose answer (the above looked quite ok, so I thought you were a bit more fluent in (makefile"-ish ;-).

Comment: I think I have made the correct adjustments, but now I get a bunch of 'undefined reference' errors. Maybe you can just post the FULL, correct working Makefile again so I do not miss something? Thanks.

Comment: The undefined can potenial come from the fact that not all .cc in the testcases are a testcase on their own, but that some of them have be linked together. Here it is very difficult to give a working solution without knowing the details.